# How to upload large file (up to 300 MB) from my pc to google drive (using Apps script)

Tags: google-apps-script, file-upload, google-drive-api, large-files

I'm new in uploading files to my google drive. I would like to upload a large file (mostly mp4) from my pc (let's say the path is "c:\xx\myfile.mp4") to my google drive (let's say to the folder "myfolder").
I have read that using the "resumable" option can solve the problem. But i don't know ho to do.
Can any one share the complete code to do this?

Comment: Why apps script?

Comment: @TheMaster I have already a web application using apps script. I would like to add the upload option.

Comment: Note that such full code tutorial or library requests are offtopic here. But you can see the [wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info), which has excellent links to resources like [this](https://github.com/tanaikech/AsynchronousResumableUploadForGoogleDrive)